# Why am I getting this "an identifier expected" error in PHPStorm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, phpstorm-2017.1

I recently updated my PHPStorm to 2017.1, after the update I saw some new errors pop up.

In this piece of code:

```
var $find_ean     = $('.' + scan_string);
```

Screenshot of the syntax highlighting

[image: Screenshot of the syntax highlighting]

I get this `an identifier expected` error, to my knowledge concatenating a selector for jQuery is allowed. I have not found the corresponding inspection to disable this or found a proper way to resolve this error. Changing the code to

```
var selector = '.' + scan_string;
var $find_ean     = $(selector);
```

Removes the error from the inspection, but I'm not really keen on the idea that I have to add in an extra line of code to resolve the inspection.

Which inspection rule is responsible for marking this code as an error?

Is there a proper way of resolving this besides adding in an extra line of code to satisfy the inspection?

- JavaScript language version is set to ECMAScript 5.1
- PHPStorm version is 2017.1 EAP

If there is any other information needed to find a solution please let me know I will update my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couse he's reading this point like you are programming in php

Comment: @MarcoSalerno But the code itself is not in a .php file. It's all contained in a .js file. As I mentioned in my question this error dit not appear before version 2017.1 in PHPStorm.

Comment: Substitute '.' with "."

Comment: @MarcoSalerno In what way would that solve the problem? The inspection error remains the same.

Comment: Well it's obviously a bug of the IDE, you can cry about it or just switch the char ^^

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Like I said the inspection error remains the same. Switching `'` for `"` didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of people are reporting this kind of issues in JavaScript files - [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35655). Some of them are: "a term expected", "unexpected token", "an identifier expected". These inspection issues are related with PhpStorm 2017.1 version. They should release update 2017.1.1 next week where these issues should be resolved.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this piece of information.

Comment: You are welcome. Have same issues, hope they will update it soon. Also there is an issue with fonts if you have noticed.

Comment: Bugfixed as of today [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26041](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26041)